# Laravel 5.2 Update Function

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I've been working on a school project in laravel, and i want to be able to update my existing records in my database, i've made a fucntion for it but when i hit the update button only the Updated_at field in my databse is updated and nothing else is, even if i change every attribute on the edit form, i've also watched and followed the Laracasts laravel fundamentals series but it gives me the same results.

This is my Store and edit method i've made for it

```
 public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //$product = Product::findOrFail($id) = finding the Id of the Product i want to update


       $product = Product::FindorFail($id);

       // Requesting a update query on the attributes: name , buy price, sell price, and the foreign_key
       $product->update($request->only(['naam', 'inkoopPrijs', 'verkoopPrijs', 'Fabrieken_Id']));

      return redirect(Route('producten.index'));
    }
```

This is the model im uing for it.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['Id', 'naam', 'inkoopPrijs', 'verkoopPrijs', 'Fabrieken_Id', 'updated_at', 'created_at'];

      protected $table = "producten";


     public function fabriek()
     {
         return $this->BelongsTo('App\Fabriek', 'Fabrieken_Id');
     }
```

when i var_dump($product) like it said in the above only the Updated_at Field updates and nothing else.

If i need any more information just let me know and i'll add it to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The update method is for MASS updates, not updates of a single record as detailed here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#updates

What you need is `save()` which updates a specific record. You can combine it with `fill()` to make it update from an array of request data.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $product = Product::FindorFail($id);
    $product->fill($request->only(['naam', 'inkoopPrijs', 'verkoopPrijs', 'Fabrieken_Id']));
    $product->save();

    return redirect(Route('producten.index'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to write like this :

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
 {        
       $product = Product::find($id);
       $product->name = $request->get('naam'); #naam : name of input field
       $product->attribute2 = $request->get('inkoopPrijs');
       $product->attribute3 = $request->get('verkoopPrijs');
       $product->attribute4 = $request->get('Fabrieken_Id');

       $product->save();
       return redirect(Route('producten.index'));    
 }
```

Or keep you update method but add this line in your Product model -

```
protected $fillable = ['name', 'attribute2', 'attribute3', 'attribute4'];
```

P.S: If you use FindOrFail then you should use try catch